# System.Threading.Timer and 49.7 days timer roll-over

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Is it safe to use System.Threading.Timer in windows service running for a long time?

In other words, is the 49.7 days timer roll-over problem fixed in Windows Server 2003 32bit + .Net Framework 2.0?

Is Thread.Sleep() the only alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal the periods are declared as `UInt32`, which does have a `MaxValue` of 4,294,967,295 , or with other words 49.7 days...so I wouldn't trust it to work the right way over such a long period. But, if I look at the reflected code, it should work if you destroy the timer every f.e. 5 days and create a new one.

**Edit:** As I think about it, Timers and Services don't play well together, you might wanna read [this](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/windows-services/31288-needs-help-timer.html) and [this](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/windows-services/27333-problem-timer.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I would like to have a definite answer. I don't have a possibility to test for 50 days.

Comment: @Den: that's definite enough.  It won't work.  If you want to kick off something that infrequently, use scheduled tasks instead of services.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows system time rollover problem has no effect on `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` (which is just a wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`).

The maximum value you can use for a timer interval is `int.MaxValue`, or 2,147,483,648 milliseconds (24.86 days). But that's just the maximum single interval you can specify. It doesn't mean that the longest your timer can run is for 25 days. That is, if you have a timer that's set to tick once every 30 seconds, it will do that for as long as your program is up. The timer won't lose its mind after 25 days and miss a tick. And it won't lose its mind after 49.7 days, either.

The reason is that those timers don't even look at the system time (`Environment.TickCount`). They're interval timers.

The idea that timers and services don't play well together is ridiculous. You don't want to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in a service because that timer depends on there being a message loop. But `System.Threading.Timer` and `System.Timers.Timer` will work very well in a service.

If you really need to set a timer interval that's longer than 2^31 milliseconds (i.e. you want your program do do something once every 30 days), you can write a managed wrapper to the Thread Pool Timer API. It lets you specify a timer interval of up to 2^63 100-nanosecond "ticks" (approximately 2^50 milliseconds, or close to 30,000 years). See [CreateThreadPoolTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682466%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and related functions.